# C++ Code runs on Linux but not on Debian GNU/Hurd

Tags: c++, linux, debian

I am trying to write an application that implements message passing on Micokernel and Monolithic systems. This code runs on Linux just fine but fails on Denbian GNU/Hurd

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MSGSZ 128

/*
 * Declare the message structure.
 */

typedef struct msgbufer {
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MSGSZ];
} message_buf;

int main()
{
    int msqid;
    int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t key;
    message_buf sbuf;
    size_t buf_length;

    /*
     * Get the message queue id for the
     * "name" 1234, which was created by
     * the server.
     */
    key = 1234;

    (void) fprintf(stderr, "\nmsgget: Calling msgget(%i,\
%#o)\n",
                   key, msgflg);

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg )) < 0) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        (void) fprintf(stderr,"msgget: msgget succeeded: msqid = %d\n", msqid);


    /*
     * We'll send message type 1
     */

    sbuf.mtype = 1;


    (void) strcpy(sbuf.mtext, "Hello other process 2.");

    buf_length = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1 ;

    /*
     * Send a message.
     */


    int err = msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buf_length, IPC_NOWAIT);

    if (err < 0) {
        printf ("%d, %li, %s, %lu\n", msqid, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.mtext, buf_length);
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(1);
    }

    else
        printf("Message: \"%s\" Sent\n", sbuf.mtext);


    exit(0);
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
send.cpp: (.text+0xf9): warning: msgsnd is not implemented and will always fail
send.cpp: (.text+0xf9): warning: msgget is not implemented and will always fail
```

Any idea?

Comment: According to this http://linux.die.net/man/3/msgsnd  the implementations of the method may depend.

Comment: Any way I can find this implementation in Debian GNU and link them them? Shold there be already an implementation there?

Comment: Really unlikely, @Elsban .The guts of Linux and Hurd are like whoa different. I rate the odds of low-level functionality like IPC written for Linux operating on a microkernel as exceptionally low. Instead I recommend finding or writing writing a portability layer to hide the Linux and Hurd ways of doing things (once you find out what the Hurd ways of doing things are (google Hurd IPC)) behind a common interface.

Comment: Thank you @user4581301, I looked for and found another example on how this can be done on Hurd. Here is the URL is someone needs it: http://walfield.org/pub/people/neal/papers/hurd-misc/